# Let $(X,T_{p})$ be the particular point topology with $p \in X$. Let $H \subseteq X$. Prove that if $p \notin H$, then $(H,T_{p|H})=(H,T_D)$

Tags: general-topology

I have tried to prove that every subset of $H$ is open in $T_{p|H}$ in this case but I've been thinking for hours and I really don't know how to start.

Comment: What is $T_D$ exactly?

Comment: yes sry, $T_D$ is the discrete topology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** A subset $S\subseteq H$ is open in $T_{p|H}$ if and only if there is an open set $U$ in $T_p$ such that $S=U\cap H$.

So, given any subset $S\subseteq H$, find $U\in T_p$ such that $S=U\cap H$.

Comment: Can S be $S=\{p\}\cup V$? I think this is valid since S exists and is open in $T_P$. As S is a subset of X which contains {p}.

Comment: Don't forget that $p\notin H$, so if $S\subseteq H$, then $S$ can't contain $p$. But you're close, the idea of taking union with $\{p\}$ is the key!

Comment: Yes, I was following my notation sry! I meant that I take $U=\{p\} \cup S$, then $S=({p\}\cupS)\capH$, since $S$ is a subset of $H$ and $H$ not contain $p$, so we can asure that equality.

Comment: @tony_matos2 Exactly that's correct! Well done!

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome.